# Method stuck in for Loop with If Conditional

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to check several entries in a game board by iterating over them in a specific order.
Now what I noticed is that when the method is called by my junit test, it is stuck in the first for loop and doesn't continue with the next ones, and just returns false, meaning it jumps to the end of the method.
When I run a test which just needs the first 3 loops, then it works, but another test requires the second loop, which doesn't get executed.

Question: Why is it jumping to the end without first checking the other loops?

```
    public boolean hasDiagonal(Mark m) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= dimension-4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= dimension-4; j++) {
            for (int k = dimension-1; k == 3; k--) {
                if (getField(i  , j  , k  ) == m &&
                    getField(i+1, j+1, k-1) == m &&
                    getField(i+2, j+2, k-2) == m &&
                    getField(i+3, j+3, k-3) == m) {
                        return true;
                    //Stops here, if this part doesn't yield true,
                    //it returns false immediately
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //This doesn't get checked
    for (int i = dimension-1; i == 3; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= dimension-4; j++) {
            for (int k = dimension-1; k <= 3; k--) {
                if (getField(i  , j  , k  ) == m &&
                    getField(i-1, j+1, k-1) == m &&
                    getField(i-2, j+2, k-2) == m &&
                    getField(i-3, j+3, k-3) == m) {
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: I've used a couple of print statements to check whats going on, and any print in the second part does not get printed. I also put everything in a while loop, which makes it stuck in the first loop-part of the above code.

Comment: Use a debugger, don't rely on print statements. Step filters will allow you to trace every single line of execution, showing you how you code is being executed. By using a debugger, you'll be able to determine where the problem is. IDEs usually come bundled with debuggers, such as Eclipse or IDEA

Comment: What's the value of dimension?  The best reason I can think of for skipping the second for loop is that dimension-1 is already 3.

Comment: if dimension is not 4, the second for loop (and all loops under it) will surely not executed.

Comment: @Warhost your modified for loop has a problem. if dimension is great than 4, the loop won't be executed, otherwise the loop might run forever (or for a long time till k cycles back to the maximum positive value) if there's no true condition of the if test ever met.

Comment: I realized, thanks. I mistaken that == with >= / <=.

Comment: @Warhost i was referring to the third for loop in the second block of your codes. it might be from your original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition part of your loops should be the problem here -

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dimension-4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= dimension-4; j++) {
        for (int k = dimension-1; k == 3; k--)
```

the innermost loop executes only if `dimension == 4` and since there is no modification within the loops to this variable.

The outermost and second loop doesn't even iterate more than once (the block would execute only once) if you do a `j++` or `i++` and at the same time check if `i/j <= dimension(4)-4` resolving as `i/j <= 0`.

So certainly the loops need better handling with dimension specified and the conditions modified accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem is indeed the k == 3, I mistaken that for "until k is 3".

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the `i == 3` and `k == 3` in your loop conditions are at least contributing to your problem. With these conditions the loops will get skipped unless `dimension == 4`.

Comment: i suspect == in those two cases should be >= or just >.

Comment: @Shiping This resolved it. Thanks a lot. Still looking into how this can be cleaner.